# How to return value PHP of request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a multiselect named `properties[]`

On my controller I tried `dd($request->get('properties'))` which returns `["1,2"]`.

However trying to get its contents using `$request->get('properties')[0]` returns key 0 undefined error.

But `$prop = ["1,2"];` `dd($prop[0]` returns `"1,2"` as expected.

Why is that?

I construct my request like this in ajax.

```
// Get selected properties. 
multiselect.getValue().forEach(element => { 
       properties.push(element.value); 
}); 

// Added selected properties to data. 
var data = form.serializeArray(); 
data.push({name: "properties[]", value: properties});
```

Comment: You need to explode the string first: `explode(',', $request->get('properties'))[0]`.

Comment: What does `gettype($request->get('properties'))` return? String or array?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `json_decode` would be a better choice in that scenario.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, you're right, but I looked at `$prop = ["1,2"];` and thought they implied an array. Anyway, it would have returned `1` and not `"1,2"`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yeah, I dunno if that's a typo or indicates OP's doing something weird on the front-end like manually constructing the `properties[]` value in a Vue component or something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @ceejayoz I am manually constructing its values via an ajax request.

Comment: @Hvel Show us how you're doing that, and please answer my `gettype` question.

Comment: ```gettype``` returns ```array```

as for the construction of the request:

```
// Get selected properties.
        multiselect.getValue().forEach(element => {
            properties.push(element.value);
        });

        // Added selected properties to data.
        var data = form.serializeArray();
        data.push({name: "properties[]", value: properties});```

Comment: Updated the question to show how request is constructed.

Answer (score -1):

I got it, and for those who may have the same problem change:

`$request->get('properties')` to `$request->input('properties')`